Quantile regression to compare two populations at different time points
I am trying to compare two different populations (e.g., 2001 and 2011) on the same variable. These are different, independent populations (this is NOT a longitudinal study; rather, two cross-sectional studies representative of the population). We have already calculated the sampling weights to apply to both samples.
I am wondering if the approach I have is correct: I would like to check, using quantile regression, whether my variable changes from 2001 to 2011 across different percentiles.
My questions are as follows:

Using R, can I use these precalculated sample weights variable within quantile regression?

If I stratify my sample according to gender, I no longer need to control for gender in the regression model?



Welcome to Cross Validated! For $#1$, what do you mean that you want to use the sample weights within the quantile regression? For $#2$, what do you mean that you no longer have to control for gender if you stratify by gender, running a regression for the men and then a totally different regression for the women?

Hello, thank you for your comment!
So 1. I have sample weights for both years that have been calculated by old colleagues to make sure our sample is representative of the population. I have this variable calculated for both study years, and I'm wondering how to best handle this variable in a quantile regression. 2. For gender, I saw previous researchers often stratify their analyses by gender, but I just wanted to make sure that if I do so, I do NOT need to control for gender in my regression model, as this will be over-controlling? Thank you!

So how do you stratify the analysis by gender? Does this mean running a separate regression for each gender?

Yes, this is my understanding of the literature!

Then what would it mean to control for gender within a regression that is limited to a single gender?

Exactly, I just wanted to make sure my reasoning was correct and that there was no point to it !

I have an additional question if possible? I have two cross-sectional survey years. Survey weights have been calculated on several variables, including two age groups : 18-40 and 41-65. Let's say that I would want to have 10-year age categories/groups in my quantile regression model, do I now need to recalculate the weights using these new 10-year groups for my results to be more accurate or can I keep the original calculated weights? Thank you very much!

A new question should be posted as a new question. Thanks!
